# The existence of planar distance preserver?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs

Let G be an n-node undirected graph, and let T be a node subset of V(G) called *terminals*.  A *distance preserver* of (G,T) is a graph H satisfying the property

$$d_H(u,v) = d_G(u,v)$$

for all nodes u, v in T. (Note that H is NOT necessarily a subgraph of G.)

For example, let G be the following graph (a) and T be the nodes on the external face. Then graph (b) is a distance preserver of (G,T).

[image]

Distance preserver with various parameters are known to exist. I'm particularly interested in the one with the following properties:

1. G is planar and unweighted (that is, all edges of G has weight one),
2. T has size $O(n^{0.5})$, and
3. H has size (the number of nodes and edges) $o(n)$. (It would be nice if we have $O(\frac{n}{\log\log n})$.)

> Does such a distance preserver exist?

If one cannot meet the above properties, any kind of relaxations are welcomed.

---

References:

- [Sparse Source-wise and Pair-wise Distance Preservers](http://www.cs.yale.edu/%7Eelkin/src.cam_ready.ps), Don Coppersmith and Michael Elkin, SIDMA, 2006.
- [Sparse Distance Preservers and Additive Spanners](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Eelkinm/add_sp.jrnl.v2.ps), Béla Bollobás, Don Coppersmith, and Michael Elkin, SIDMA, 2005.
- [Spanners and emulators with sublinear distance errors](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/theoryseminar/papers/Thorup-Zwick-sublinear-additive-error.pdf), Mikkel Thorup and Uri Zwick, SODA, 2006.
- [Lower Bounds for Additive Spanners, Emulators, and More](https://web.archive.org/web/20110107053409/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/cs/people/dpwoodru/w06b.pdf), David P. Woodruff, FOCS, 2006.

Distance preserver is also known as an *emulator*; many related work can be found on internet by searching the term *spanner*, which requires H to be a subgraph of G. But in my applications we can use other graphs as well, as long as H preserves the distances between T in G.

Comment: −1 for using JPEG for this kind of figure!  (just joking, but PNG is usually much better in both image quality and file size for simple figures)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thanks for the useful tips! I did not know that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many years later, it looks like OP has finally answered his own question: [Near-Optimal Distance Emulator for Planar Graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01478.pdf) by Hsien-Chih Chang, Paweł Gawrychowski, Shay Mozes, and Oren Weimann was just posted on the arxiv.

The answer to the original question is yes: it is shown that $\widetilde{O}(\min\{t^2, \sqrt{tn}\})$ edges suffice to preserve distances between $|T| =: t$ terminals, which is optimal up to log factors.  In particular $\widetilde{O}(n^{3/4})$ edges suffice for the setting in the OP.  This preserver can also be computed in $\widetilde{O}(n)$ time; I would strongly suspect that the log factors in the size can be removed if we care only about existence and not computation time of the preserver, but I have not rigorously verified this.

(On a less formal note, I find this result really amazing.  Congrats!)

Comment: Thank you @GMB for posting it as an answer.  A small catch here is that the preserver is _directed_; it is an open question whether an undirected (but still not necessarily planar) emulator of sublinear-size exists.  But it is quite satisfying to finally know the answer to an old question after all these years :)

Answer (score 2):

you may want to look at Klein's planar subset spanner, which preserves distances up to a 1+epsilon factor.

A Subset Spanner for Planar Graphs, with Application to Subset TSP
http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1132516.1132620

Comment: Thanks, I've read the paper, and there's a gap between his construction and our requirements. It seems that any spanner won't work as long as it is a subgraph of the original graph; one can take a grid graph as a counter-example. But there are emulators for the grid graphs.

Comment: another construction idea, maybe it works?

1) recursively apply shortest-path separators (Thorup, FOCS'01)

2) eps-cover for each vertex
[first two steps construct distance labels]
there are sqrt{n} terminals, each with a label of size O(log n / eps), connecting to a total number of at most sqrt{n}*log n paths and 1/eps times more portals

3) shortcut the portals on paths by weighted edges and shortcut the connections to portals by edges

the resulting graph should have roughly sqrt{n}*log n vertices and edges (up to eps) and represent 1+eps shortest paths

for exact distances I don't know...